# Outlook 2010 - Create email from Appointment reminder - multiple categories

Tags: vba, email, outlook

**Program:** Outlook 2010

**Requirement:**
To send an email when an appointment trigger fires.  More than 1 category will be used.

**Issue:**
The calendar shows the correct category from the 2nd part of the VBA code, however when the email triggers it reverts to the 1st category and sends using those parameters.  The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Categories <> "Cat - Test (1)" Then
    objMsg.To = Item.Location
    objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject & " | " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
    objMsg.HTMLBody = Format(Now, "Long Date") & Item.Body
    objMsg.CC = "email"
    objMsg.BCC = "email 1, 2, 3"
    objMsg.Categories = "Cat - Test (1)"
    objMsg.Send

    'this is the code that reverts to the one above at the time of sending, _
    'but looks as it should in the calendar preview.
    ElseIf Item.Categories <> "Cat - Test (2)" Then
    objMsg.To = Item.Location
    objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject & " | " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
    objMsg.HTMLBody = Format(Now, "Long Date") & Item.Body
    objMsg.CC = "email"
    objMsg.BCC = "emails"
    objMsg.Categories = "Cat - Test (2)"
    objMsg.Send
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any advice, it seems I may be missing perhaps some sort of end, or a correct way of using `IF / elseIF`  I have tried adding & omitting some of the IF, ElseIF, but I can't get it to trigger correctly.

I have also created a calendar appointment without a category, but with an email in the 'location' field, and it still triggers the macro to run.

[image: Correct Cal view, Incorrect on Send]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at your code if the `Item.Categories` has a value of "Cat - Test (2)" then you are going to set the `objMsg.Categories` to "Cat - Test (1)". Is this what you are intending? If not try replacing the `<>` with `=` in your if/elseif statements.

Comment: @GrahamAnderson thank you, that is my answer.  If you write it as the answer I can mark it up for you.  Brilliant!

Comment: You're welcome, have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code if the `Item.Categories` has a value of `"Cat - Test (2)"` then you are going to set the `objMsg.Categories` to `"Cat - Test (1)"`, try replacing the `<>` with `=` in your if/elseif statements.